# Is `require "rubygems"` returning `false` ok?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-2.1

Requiring `"rubygems"` gives `false`, but requiring `"appium_lib"` gives `true`. I.e.,

```
require 'rubygems' # => false
require 'appium_lib' # => true
```

Is this ok? This is not like trying to require something that really doesn't exist, i.e.:

```
require 'does_not_existxxxxxxx' # => LoadError: cannot load such file -- does_not_existxxxxxxx
```

Comment: I think the Ruby developers would be extremely grateful if you could file a bug and tell them what you find unclear about [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require): "`require(name)` → `true` or `false`: Loads the given `name`, returning `true` if successful and `false` if the feature is already loaded."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be fine. Requiring a file the second time results in a false response. With `load`, it's a different thing, which would `load` (`require`) the file each time it is requested.

So it just means that irb is starting with `rubygems` already required, which is not a surprise.

For example, `load` is heavily used in Rails' development mode, so your changes can immediately be shown.

Since Ruby 1.9 rubygems are automatically required.

Comment: Probably, you may like to add that `require "rubygems"` was needed in older versions of Ruby, but not in newer versions.

Answer (score 3):

When you `require` a gem, really you’re just placing that gem’s **lib** directory onto your **$LOAD_PATH**. If it returns false all that means is that it is already in your **$LOAD_PATH**.

[Requiring a Gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#requiring-code)